# If statement compatibility issue in Swift (it worked before)

Tags: if-statement, swift, types, compatibility

i reopened a project i stop working on for some days and without edditing any line, when i tried to run it, it gave me two errors i never saw before and i persoanlly think they make no sense. Please help me, the code is like this:

```
if  normals == true && numberOfTaps > highScoreN.integerForKey("highscoren") || normals == 1 && highScoreN.integerForKey("highscoren") == 0
```

It gives me this error: "Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '($T16, $T31)'"

and in another line, which is practically the same:

```
if  pros == true && numberOfTaps > highScoreP.integerForKey("highscorep") || pros == 1 && highScoreP.integerForKey("highscorep") == 0
```

It gives me this error: "Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '($T16, $T31)'"

I repeat, it had worked properly some days before, i dont know why it isn't..
Thank you so much!

PSD:// highScoreP and highScoreN are NSUserDefault type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on the `==` in both lines, so that narrows it down. The only place you have `==` is comparing the `normals` variable to `true` and `1`. Swift is very type safe, so your normals variable cannot be both `true` (a boolean) and `1` (an Int). Check the type of your `normals` variable and proceed form there.

Comment: after doing that, im getting errors in the appdelegate, which i never touched... its like xcode is against me, when i change what you told me (to true) im getting in this line (insede the Appdelegate): error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict) with the error : "'errorWithDomain(_:code:userInfo:)' is unavailable: use object construction 'NSError(domain:code:userInfo:)'"

Comment: It's not Xcode, it is Swift which is a rapidly evolving language.

Comment: I'm hoping that Apple rapidly evolves those error messages though.  They are something that only a compiler engineer could love.

Comment: i solved it by deleting the line, i hope is not important, lol